# Javascript/PHP popup page problem

Tags: javascript

I have a program in PHP that allows user to pop in a message, for confirmation from user. As seen below is the link i used.

From **inbox.php**:

```
echo "<a href='inbox.php' onclick=\"popup('acknowledge.php?id=$id')\"><font size=1px color=maroon>acknowledge</font></a></td>";
```

From **acknowledge.php**:

```
if ($_POST['no']) {

    header("location: inbox.php");
    }

?>

<body bgcolor=skyblue>
<center><form name=form1 method=post>
<b><u> Acknowledge Message </u></b><br><br>
Are you sure yout want to acknowledge this message?<br><br>
<input type=button name=yes value="Yes">
&nbsp;
<input type=submit name="no" value="No">
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

The problem is, everytime i click "no", to go back from previous page. It sets the page size the same as the popup page. It becomes smaller too. What's the problem? Answers are very much appreciated.

Here is the code for popup():

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

<!-- function popup(url) {
     var width  = 500;
     var height = 135;
     var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
     var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;
     var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
     params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
     params += ', directories=no';
     params += ', location=no';
     params += ', menubar=no';
     params += ', resizable=no';
     params += ', scrollbars=no';
     params += ', status=no';
     params += ', toolbar=no';
     newwin=window.open(url,'windowname5', params);
     if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
               return false;
    }
                // -->

</script>
```

Comment: What is the code of the function named `popup`?

Comment: Hi Alsciende, I placed my code for popup. hope you can help me figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because you are setting the url to the new win instead of the current window?

Comment: Pardon me,I didn't quite get what you mean? The popup() function is inside my inbox.php, upon clicking, it will open the popup page (new win) named "acknowledge.php". But when i exit/cancel, by clicking "No" button, it returns to inbox.php (just what i wanted) but with smaller page size. :(